# Get Multi-Select Attribute Values without commas

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I'm using this to display values of a multi select attribute.

```
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_name')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```

The result is value1, value2, value3

Can someone suggest how to replace the commas with line breaks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There have any function  does `not exits which is give result like comment with line break in a single code`.

**You can try the below**

```
$values=explode(',',$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_name')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product));

$Result=implode(",\n",$values);
```

Comment: I get "Array", instead of a list of values.

Comment: have you tried  $Result?

Comment: Yes!  Perfect! (I forgot echo).  Thank you so much for the speedy, expert assist!